# Magento 2 How can I override core system.xml file

Tags: magento, magento2

**I am using Magento 2.2.3 version.** I have facing the problem in override core Magento CatalogInventory system xml file.

**In default magento 2 backorders system configuration setting is global. I want to change that setting website wise.**
For this i have created one module in which etc/adminhtml directory i have created system.xml. Here is my custom module system.xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="cataloginventory" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="50" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <group id="item_options" translate="label comment" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <field id="backorders" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="3" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0" canRestore="1">
                    <label>Backorders</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Source\Backorders</source_model>
                    <backend_model>Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Config\Backend\Backorders</backend_model>
                    <comment>Changing can take some time due to processing whole catalog.</comment>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

I have research in google and found this link :
https://inchoo.net/magento-2/allow-backorders-website-scope/
but it's did not worked for me.

**I want to override Magento_CatalogInventory system.xml file and change backorders setting  showInWebsite from 0 to 1.**

Can you please help me for override or change core system.xml file in my custom module ?

Comment: Did you add a dependency to the Magento_CatalogInventory module in your modules declaration? Did you clear cache after activating your module?

Comment: Thanks @sharathkumar . it is working after delete cache folder from var. Due to  cache  not reflecting my changes in admin.